# cant get cypress to work with typescript using CRA

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cypress

I am trying to get typescript to work with cypress in a react app I created using `create-react-app`. I followed all the information in [this](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/05/13/code-create-react-app-v3-and-its-cypress-tests-using-typescript/) article, but when I try to run a test file, I get the following error.

> Conflicting definitions for 'react' found at....

I am using CRA v3 as the article suggests.

This is what I have in my tsconfig.json in my cypress folder.

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "include": [
      "../node_modules/cypress",
      "*/*.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
      "noEmit": false
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think there isn't enough information for us to help you. What have you tried? What do you think is the cause? Does it tell you where the conflicting definitions are?

Comment: OP, have you found a fix for this?